# Override user roles magento admin

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, multistore, overrides, role

I just want override the user roles in the magento admin panel so that each store can have separate admin say Store Admin, Can anybody suggest a way to filter the stores for multiple Store Admins?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199605/how-to-configure-multiple-admin-users-to-multiple-websites-in-one-installation-i

I also wanted to have this feature, you can check the answer made by 'Joseph Mastey' and see the links that he posted there. :)